# Getting value of TextCtrl from a different wxPanel

Tags: python, wxpython

I was trying to get my first wxWindow application to work and I ran into following difficulty:
I create wxPanel and add a wxNotebook object to it. Then I add a page to notebook created from another wxPanel object. How do I access a value of TextCtrl from first wxPanel in the second one?

```
import wx

class BasicApp(wx.App):
  def OnInit(self):
    frame = BasicFrame(None, -1, "Test App")
    panel = BasicPanel(frame, -1);
    frame.Show(True)
    self.SetTopWindow(frame)
    return True;

class BasicFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title,
                     wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(400, 300))
    self.CreateStatusBar()

class BasicPanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

    self.lblText1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Text1:");
    self.txtText1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1001, "Text1", size = wx.Size(140, -1));
    self.line1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL);
    self.line1.Add(self.lblText1, 0, wx.EXPAND);
    self.line1.Add(self.txtText1, proportion=1, flag=wx.LEFT, border=5);

    self.nb = wx.Notebook(self, -1);
    tab1 = Tab1(self.nb, -1);
    self.nb.AddPage(tab1, "Tab1");

    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.line1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.SetAutoLayout(1)
    self.sizer.Fit(self)
    self.Show(1)

class Tab1(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id);

    self.lblText2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Text2:");
    self.txtText2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1101, "Text2", size = wx.Size(140, -1));
    self.line1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL);
    self.line1.Add(self.lblText2, 0, wx.EXPAND);
    self.line1.Add(self.txtText2, 0, wx.EXPAND);

    self.lblMessage = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Message:");
    self.txtMessage = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1102, "", style = wx.TE_MULTILINE);

    self.cmdCreate = wx.Button(self, 1103, "Create");
    self.cmdCreate.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Create_OnClick)
    self.line3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL);

    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.line1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(self.lblMessage, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(self.txtMessage, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(self.cmdCreate, 0, wx.LEFT)

    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.SetAutoLayout(1)
    self.sizer.Fit(self)
    self.Show(1)
  def Create_OnClick(self, event):
    text1 = "";
    text2 = self.txtText2.GetValue();
    self.txtMessage.SetValue(text1 + " " + text2);

app = BasicApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

To be more specific I want to be able to access value of txtText1 in Create_OnClick() method. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to pass the control to the constructor of the tab, then you can directly reference it. For example:

```
class Tab1(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, textCtrl1):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id);
    self.textCtrl1 = textCtrl1
  ...
  def Create_OnClick(self, event):
    text1 = self.textCtrl1
```

Another solution is to move the Create_OnClick handler to the base panel since it knows about all of the other panels (and thus, their children). Or, create a separate controller class that knows about the various widgets and can have handlers that act on behalf of them all.